# How can we ask a question which is closely related with the question we got answer?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In some cases after asking a question we feel that why the ther case may not be there or it is quite interesting a case regarding the question too after the answer has been posted.  In these cases how can we ask a question which is closely related with the question we got answer? And If i have a question regarding other person's question and if I wish to post question highly related with that, What should I do?

Like the [following link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206777/drawing-arrows-on-curves-and-shading-regions-in-tikz/%22Try%20this%22): here I have added the new question in the same question box itself. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did over on TeX (adding "**Additional Question** Thank you so much for your answer. But I have one more doubt") is a practice that's pretty uniformly discouraged across Stack Exchange. "Chameleon" questions that turn into something else after being answered are   annoying to some answerers, and are difficult to follow for outside readers. Instead:

1. If you find that answers are incomplete, point this out to the answerers.
2. If they cannot fill in the details, post a bounty (e.g., "improve details" reason)
3. If the issue is not that the answerers missed something, but rather you thought of another thing to ask... then you should ask a new question, and link to the original one. When doing so, be sure to make the new question self-contained: readers should not have to travel to another question just to figure out  what is being asked.